# Prevent vim from loading sessions when reading from stdin

Tags: session, vim, stdin

I've been customizing my `.vimrc` a lot lately and love the power and convenience that `:mksession` gives me. I currently have the following in my `.vimrc` to autoload sessions:

```
function! LoadSession()                                                              
  if argc() == 0 && ! &diff                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    let g:sessiondir = $HOME . "/.vim/sessions" . getcwd()                           
    let g:sessionfile = g:sessiondir . "/session.vim"                                
    if (filereadable(g:sessionfile))                                                 
      exe 'source ' g:sessionfile                                                    
    else                                                                             
      echo "No session loaded." + argc() + argv()                                    
    endif                                                                            
  else                                                                               
    let g:sessionfile = ""                                                           
    let g:sessiondir = ""                                                            
    call ResCur()                                                                    
  endif                                                                              
endfunction
```

I then call this with `au VimEnter * nested :call LoadSession()`. This works great for most cases, except when vim is reading from `stdin`. In that case the session is still loaded, however I want to prevent that from happening. I would have thought the `argc() == 0` conditions would be enough, but it appears that the `-` that vim is being called with to read from `stdin` causes `argc()` to not return 0. Poop! ;]

I've tried all sorts of things from looking at `argv(0)` (it's empty in this case - why?), trying to find ways of identifying that vim is reading from `stdin` (it shows a message that it's doing so, but I can't figure out how to tap into that), etc., but no luck so far.

I'm sure I'm missing something terribly obvious here, but the Googles and vim `:help` isn't getting me anywhere, so I'm hoping some kind soul here can shed some light on this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [session.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3150) that I'm using offers extended session handling. Among others, it asks whether a previously saved session should be restored on Vim startup.

But unless you need the other functionality of the plugin, your workaround with mappings triggering the restore is probably fine, too.

Comment: I'm trying out session.vim right now, can't make the autoload work the way I want to yet, but this is looking promising, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What I found works is having

```
autocmd StdinReadPre * let g:my_is_stdin = 1
```

in your `.vimrc` and then test for `exists("g:my_is_stdin")` in your session saving/loading functions. Mind that these have to be run also via `autocmd` on events `VimLeave`/`VimEnter` for this scheme to work.

Answer (score 0):

I've been fiddling a lot with loading sessions on Vim startup, and ultimately decided that's it's not a very good idea, mainly because it doesn't work well with plugins.

I ultimately added some mappings for saving and restoring a session. This has the bonus that you don't have to mess arround with your session when you're doing quick edits.

```
map <leader>ss :call CustomSessionSave()<CR>
map <leader>sl :call CustomSessionRestore()<CR>
map <leader>sd :call CustomSessionDelete()<CR>
```

Maybe this helps

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for an autoloading solution. By the way: what are those `CustomSessionXXX()` functions you're calling?

Comment: nothing special, I'm just closing NERDTree before calling `mksession` (on Save) and then opening it on Restore.